# What does the Quran or Hadith say about Nakedness within a marriage?

Tags: nikah, sharia

My husband is a Muslim and we have been married for 5 months and I have not seen his whole body. He keeps himself covered with a towel around the house, and sex is done under the cover or in the dark.

Is this an Islamic thing or is it my husband?

*Please provide reference from Quran or Hadith.*

Answer (score 2):

Islam has allowed nudity between a husband and a wife.  It's something Prophet Mohammed himself did.

Allah said in Surah al-Muminun 23:5-6 =

**"And those who guard their modesty, except from their wives or that their right hands possess, for then, they are free from blame."**

The words translated as "their modesty" is "layforujihim" of which rooted in "fa raa jeem" meaning modest or chaste.

So Allah is allowing us to expose ourselves and not be modest with our wives.

It's well known that the Prophet Mohammed use to take baths together with his wife using one vessel.  The hadiths are found in Sahih al-Bukhari, Sahih Muslim, Sunan Abu Dawud.

Comment: You're saying all that information was found in Hadith? Can you define Hadith?

Comment: The ayah alone proves that it's okay.  I used hadith to show the Prophet was naked with his wife.

Answer (score -1):

The to the point answer here would be that your husband is doing all this just according to Islam.

Islam prohibits us from nudity, although it is not a sin to watch your couple's body but while having sex, one must turn off lights or cover their body.

It would help you both to have sex for sake of children and not to have sex for the sake of sex. It would lessen the chances of having other bad sexual thoughts at that time.

May Allah bless your husband to always follow teachings of Islam.

Comment: Sources on that?

Comment: what is your source for this: 

...one must turn off lights or cover their body.